# Allow a user to select a folder on an SD card

Tags: android

I'm looking for a way to allow a user to press a button to browse the contents of the SD card, and then select a folder, whose path will be returned to the application. Similar to how you pull up the "Browse..." dialog on Windows for installations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so what I ended up doing was just using a ListActivity with a ListView (choiceMode:simple_list_item_multiple_choice) where the user can check the folders they wish to use. Then I used a custom layout that placed a Submit button below the ListView, which the user can press to confirm the selection.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built into Android for it AFAIK. You can integrate something like [OpenIntents File Manager](http://www.openintents.org/en/filemanager), but that is a separate APK that users would need to install.

Comment: I thought this might be the case...

It's weird that you can pull up the gallery for a photo chooser, and it has an option to select multiple images, but you can't really do anything with that selection, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AndroXplorer](http://www.androxplorer.com/blog/?p=71), the hook is quite simple, but then again, yes, it is another APK to install